Text inside SafeAreaView hidden behind Pixel 8 Pro camera notch
I'm using SafeAreaView from react-native-safe-area-contex, but it doesn't seem to be working correctly with Pixel 8 Pro.

Here's how I used it in the component:
import { Text } from "react-native";
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { useLayoutEffect } from "react";
import { SafeAreaView } from "react-native-safe-area-context";

const HomeScreen = () => {

    const navigation = useNavigation();

    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        navigation.setOptions({
            headerShown: false
        })
    });

    return (
        <SafeAreaView>
            <Text>This is some text that shouldn't be hidden behind the camera notch but on Pixel it is</Text>
        </SafeAreaView>
    )
}

export default HomeScreen

Am I using it incorrectly?

You should add SafeAreaProvider in your app's root component.
<SafeAreaProvider>
    ...
    <HomeScreen />
    ...
</SafeAreaProvider>

More information in the docs.
